# Make an image a hyperlink

Tags: html, image, href

I'm trying to add a hyperlink to an image. I thought it would require wrapping everything in an a tag (not pictured below), but I'm not having luck. Can you help?

Here's the code:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><script id = "countable-message-lawmaker" src = "https://assets.countable.us/widgets/message-your-lawmaker/countable-message-lawmaker.js" type = "text/javascript" async>
```

Comment: But where is the image? There's only a `<p>` and a `<script>` tags.

Comment: Hi, where is your `a` and `img` tags?

Comment: It's a little gray icon in my editor. Looks like a movie symbol. Is any of that making sense?

Comment: Makes sense, but I think you've copied the wrong code across in your question :)

Comment: the js produces an image, assuming this is what she would like to be a hyperlink.  Just wrap the whole thing in a <a><a/> tag.